# SYMFONY 5.4.12 mnastalski/przelewy24-php veryfication

Tags: symfony, payment-gateway

Hello I'v got a question about integration solution  mnastalski/przelewy24-php in SYMFONY framework ver. 5.4.12.

I hacve a code:

```
namespace App\Controller;
...
use Przelewy24\Przelewy24;
use Przelewy24\Exceptions\Przelewy24Exception;
...
public function myAccount(
   $partnerId = XXXXXX;
   $crc = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
   $live = false;
...
if ($buyPointsForm->isSubmitted() && $buyPointsForm->isValid()) {
        $session_id = session_id();
        $przelewy24 = new Przelewy24([
            'merchant_id' => $partnerId,
            'crc' => $crc,
            'live' => $live,
        ]);
        try {
            $transaction = $przelewy24->transaction([
                'session_id' => $session_id,
                'url_return' => '.../assign_points/'.$item->getId().'/'.intVal($item->getPoints()).'/33',
                'url_status' => '.../admin/my-account',
                'amount' => 10,
                'description' => 'Test',
                'email' =>  'sample@sample.pl'
            ]);
            $transaction->token();
            $transaction->redirectUrl();
            $webhook = $przelewy24->handleWebhook();
           
            return $this->redirect($url);
        } catch (Przelewy24Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
    }
enter code here
```

Its works in a test environment, but no matter what feedback I do, always in service added points to user.

How i can modify this code to check verify transaction?

Thx for all answers !
Greatings !

Comment: "always in service added points to user" - what does that mean?

Comment: If i do cancelled transaction, status is not respected system added points normaly. 
I think i have to make ->verifyTransaction

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe that code would be more readable.

```
$przelewy24 = new Przelewy24([
            'merchant_id' => 'XXXXXX',
            'crc' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'live' => false,
        ]);
        $session_id = session_id();
        try {
            $transaction = $przelewy24->transaction([
                'session_id' => $session_id,
                'url_return' => '....../admin/my-account',
                'url_status' => '....../add-points/'.$item->getId().'/'.intVal($item->getPoints()).'/33',
                'amount' => 9,
                'description' => 'Test subject',
                'email' => $item->getEmail()
            ]);
            $transaction->token();
            $transaction->redirectUrl();
            $webhook = $przelewy24->handleWebhook();
            return $this->redirect($transaction->redirectUrl());
        } catch (Przelewy24Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
```

I  changed url_return and url_status. Effect the same but maybe i need however send to url_status linik with responsible content?